# terminology for upward devolution from modules to framework

Tags: terminology, object-oriented-design, anti-patterns, modules, separation-of-concerns

Is there a word for the problem of a framework becoming married to the software modules it supports, for example adding methods to a base class that may apply only to certain subclasses or use cases? It's a particular kind of violation of separation of concerns.

The words that come to mind are "upward devolution" or "feature capture," but these seem to belong to politics, not engineering. Wikipedia has an article on "[subsidiarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsidiarity)" which mentions politics and object-oriented programming in the same sentence, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: How about a "blurring/merging of concerns", or maybe "recoupling"?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like an increase in coupling, so the framework and associated modules are becoming more tightly coupled to each other.

"Tight coupling" adequately captures all of the challenges / issues you're mentioning.